# Java Binary SE execution stucked when running from java code

Tags: java, automation

I want to run external *.jar file for my automation test code. This jar file executable is mocking some api services neeed for my test.
I run it in my code using:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "./jarpath/yourjar.jar");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String s = "";
while((s = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(s);
}
int status = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with status: " + status);
```

but somehow service is started and doesnt leave function.

After starting jar file in cmd terminal, I can see info: "Started Application", but its stucked in the same line. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: You must read both  the outputs generated or it will hang when the buffer is full

Comment: Try adding `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` before `start()`, this avoids needing background thread on stderr.

Comment: If the JAR is mocking an API, it is probably designed to continue running as a server. This code waits for it to exit. Are you sure that’s what you want?

Comment: yes, I want to run it in background, but I dont want it to block my code execution.